# Dynamic Product Names Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2

The majority of our customers enter a search on the homepage of our site.

Let's say user1 enters search123.
& User2 enters mysearch789

Is it possible when the customer reaches the product list and product page that the product can show

For User1 = (product name) - search123

For User2 = (product name) - mysearch789

It's a custom search we have on our homepage that returns values from an external source. I was looking for the products in the Magento db to have the value returned from the external db appended to the title in website. This would be different for every customer.

Comment: can you expand a little more what you are trying to achieve? Are you looking to filter against this data later, or trying to track product searches in relation to sales?

Comment: @Ryan Please provide more detail and if possible then screen-shot

Comment: Do you want to display the search term which the customer used to land on that PLP or PDP?Well anyways the customer will never be redirected to PLP through search instead its a catalog search result page which already displays the search term below the breadcrumbs on that page.